# Why does the array name print strings in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

In C,

```
char a[3] = "a";
printf("%u %u",a,&a);
```

a and &a both print the address.
I learned that an array name represents the address of the first element.

But in C++,

```
char arr[30] = "string";
cout << arr;
```

When I tried to print this, I found out that the computer prints strings, not an address.
Why does the array name print strings, not an address? Why is this happening in c++?

Comment: An array is an array and a pointer is a pointer, an array is not a pointer. Arrays can implicitly convert to pointers to their first element but they are not pointers.